# Updating a app widget with a Handler on a Service

Tags: java, android, service, widget, handler

I want an android app widget to update periodically. I used a `Handler` for that purpose as I want it to update more frequently(once in a minute). Having the `Handler` declared on `onEnabled()` call of the widget works as expected. But it fails sometimes. The widget doesn't upgrade and by logging I found that `Handler` becomes `null`. So I declared a `Service` to update the widget and declared the `Handler` and updated with it. Now all my widget does is start the service in `onEnabled()` call and stops it on `onDisabled()` call. The `Service` is running always and updates the widget. The code:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    handler=new Handler();
    runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ComponentName appWidget=new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),widget.class.getName());
            AppWidgetManager widgetManager= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            int ids[]=widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(appWidget);
            for(int id:ids)
            {
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetLayout);
//Update Widget here                     
        widgetManager.updateAppWidget(id, views);
            }
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    };
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handler.post(runnable);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Is this the best method to update the widgets? Because this would mean users can kill the service with task killers which will cause the widget to function improperly and if the device reboots then the service won't be running. So how to get rid of this and update the widget? or Is there a more efficient way to update the widget very frequently and reliably? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be more sure that you won't run into improper behavior as you describe, you should remove this from your process and let some other component take care of your update interval. The `AlarmManager` has a function that can do this for you: `public void setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)`.

You can use it like this

```
AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
aManager.setRepeating(/*clock_type*/, /*first trigger*/, /*update time*/, /*action*/);
```

You can find the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

By moving the functionality you want to the `AlarmManager`, it does not matter if your application gets killed. Because the `AlarmManager` will send you a new `Intent` you process will be brought back to life and your widget will remain working properly

Also, if you are working with widgets, you might want to take a look at `AppWidgetProvider` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html). It is specifically made to create and control widgets

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried using 'AlarmManager' from within the widget. It worked but it also fails sometimes and my widget gets freezed. Thats why I am using Handler.

Comment: I don't think that makes much of difference as long as the call to the AlarmManager is made. I'm surprised to hear that it fails sometime

Comment: Yes. Sometimes I see the widget just getting freezed without updating. Even when I used a handler to update from within the widget, this happen. The update works when I manually trigger the update from the configuration activity. But not with the AlarmManager or the handler.